# The Eunuch being converted by Phillip?

Tags: soteriology, evangelicalism, evangelism

There is a passage in the Bible talks about an eunuch traveling on the road and reading from Isaiah. The Phillip saw him, talked to him, and baptized him. Which passage is it? Is that passage enough to prove that repentance, faith, and therefore salvation is not necessarily followed by an emotional experience, but it is as decision to follow Christ? Especially if one has grown up in the church and taught to obey the 10 commandments anyway? Also, do we have an account of Timothy's (or someone else who grew up in the church) salvation?  Thanks.

Comment: Philip and the Ethiopian: Acts 8:26-40.

Comment: As for your first question (about an emotional experience accompanying conversion), how do you know the Ethiopian treasurer was NOT emotional after Philip led him to the Lord?  In general, however, the Bible does not guarantee that each one of us upon conversion will have an "emotional experience."  The same goes for being miraculously delivered from drug addiction, sexual sins, cursing, prejudice, bigotry, violence, chronic anger, and perhaps a score of other besetting sins.  Sometimes God does deliver us instantly (praise Him!), but other times, not.  God converts originals, not duplicates!

Comment: @rhetorician well just the way the story is narrated it makes me think that the eunuch was just listening carefully, then Phillip asked him, he said yes, and he was saved. And about the emotional experience, what do you think about some preachers today who say you have to feel sorrow for your sin, otherwise it is not true repentance? Is it possible to come to true repentance and not really feel sorrow?

Comment: @rhetorician and of course I know I could be completely wrong on what actually took place with the eunuch

Comment: @Ovi:  The preachers you refer to may--I say MAY--have a point.  I, however, prefer to say that repentance involves, in part, saying "I'm sorry" to God and MEANING it.  Do you necessarily need to feel sorry?  Frankly, I don't know.  The apostle Paul talks about "the sorrow that is according to the will of God produces a repentance without regret, leading to salvation, but the sorrow of the world produces death" (2 Corinthians 7:10).  What does this verse say to you personally?

Comment: @rhetorician thanks for your answer. The verse seems like it could refer to the sorrow of sinning, but it seems like it could also mean the sorrow that we are hell bound without Christ.

Comment: Which passage is it? -> Isaiah 53:7-8 (Septuagint)

Comment: There are quite a few questions in there, which ideally should be posted separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, notice that after being baptised, the eunuch went on his way rejoicing, which is an expression of joy, which some would call an emotional experience. Whether or not it is, it flies in the face of the suggestion that obedience to God and joy are unconnected. There are many scriptures which underline the link between joy and righteouness. Here are 2:

> You have loved righteousness and hated lawlessness;
>   Therefore God, Your God, has anointed You
>   With the oil of gladness more than Your companions.”
>   (Hebrews 1.9)
>
> If you keep My commandments, you will abide in My love, just as I have kept My Father’s commandments and abide in His love.
>   “These things I have spoken to you, that My joy may remain in you, and that your joy may be full.
>   (John 15,10+11)

Comment: This is good, but I think I should've mentioned that I was focusing more on an experience of sorrow rather than joy.

Comment: Thanks. Praise the Lord. Being saved certainly wouldn't cause sorrow. In Psalm 51 David refers to the joy of God's salvation: 'Restore to me the joy of Your salvation,
And uphold me by Your generous Spirit.' (Psalm 51.12).

Comment: Yes faith causes joy, but I was wondering about some of the preachers today who say that unless you feel sorrow for your sins you have not really repented. For example, this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FfJTPkrQdZE   talks about that. John MacArthur has a sermon which is basically the same thing, and Paul Washer also says that if you really reached true repentance you should feel sorrow and some people even weep for their sins. Then comes the joy of salvation when you trust in Jesus.

Comment: continued: Do you think that is accurate in regards to the experience of the eunuch and other parts of the Bible?

Comment: Sin certainly causes sorrow. God himself was so upset by people's continual sin that He flooded the earth and destroyed most of mankind. I'm sure most people have cried many times in their lives, and this is because of sin. Without sin, there will be no more crying for those who make it to heaven: 'And God will wipe away every tear from their eyes; there shall be no more death, nor sorrow, nor crying. There shall be no more pain, for the former things have passed away.”' (Rev 21.4). In this world though, we will have to cry because of the trouble that people' sins cause us and them.

Comment: Sin grieves The Holy Spirit and so the more we are filled with The Holy Spirit, the more grieved we will be by people's sins. Also, if we commit sin after being born again, we will feel His grief. There are different types of sorrow though: 'For godly sorrow produces repentance leading to salvation, not to be regretted; but the sorrow of the world produces death.' (2 Cor 7.10). I certainly experienced sorrow when I saw children starving in Africa on tv when I was a teenager before I was born again. I  cried out 'Why is there so much suffering in the world?' and I believe God answered me.

Comment: Whether you should feel sorrow if you've reached true repentance I don't know, but I think everyone has felt sorrow anyway, so they seem to meet the alleged prerequisite. However, some people feel sorrow and don't repent, so feeling sorrow doesn't mean you've repented, but I'm sure everyone who has repented has done so because they experienced the sorrow of a sinful life and prefer the joy of a godly one. Some people have to go through more than sorrow before they fully yield to God though: they have to become physically sick. I know because I've been one of them.

Comment: alright, thanks for your answer, and you had to go trough sickness but all that matters is that you're saved now, and that's awesome.

Comment: No probs: it was actually after being saved that I've had to go through sickness as a result of clinging onto things God didn't want me to be doing. It's been a refining process: God prunes every branch even when it's bearing fruit, so it can bear more fruit. Pruning is painful, but good, as you may know. ' Now no chastening seems to be joyful for the present, but painful; nevertheless, afterward it yields the peaceable fruit of righteousness to those who have been trained by it.' (Hebrews 12.11)

Comment: It is awesome that I'm saved now. I pray we'll all make it to heaven, whilst I realise that not everyone will.